# How to identify multiple Objects in a JSON file programmatically in Android

Tags: android, json, arrays

I have a JSON file like below.

```
{
"user":
    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "firstname":"Xyz",
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "firstname":"Abc",
        }           
    ],

"animal":
    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "firstname":"Elephant",
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "firstname":"Horse",
        }
    ]   
}
```

In the server side, they are updating this JSON file with new parent JSON Objects. As an example as you can see, there are "user" and "animal" Objects. Server may add another object call "birds" with the same attributes "id" and "firstname".

What I need is to find out the parent Objects programmatically and extract their names.

If the JSON file is a static file, I am able to read and get the out-put. What I am asking here is a way to find parent JSONObjects.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(uriToJsonFile);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("user");
```

If I able to do what I am asking for, we no need to hard-code the value "user" in `jsonObject.getJSONArray("user");` instead we can pass that value programmatically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method call `names' in **JSONObject** class.

```
JSONArray objNames = jsonObject.names();
System.out.println(objNames.toString());
```

When you run this code you can get following out-put

> ["user","animal"]

It shows all the parent Objects

Answer (score 2):

```
jsonObject.getNames(jsonObject);
```

This return all keys in the object.. hope this is what you wanted...

Comment: I cannot find any method called `getNames()` in the four class (JSONArray, JSONObject, JSONStringer and JSONTokener) in Android. Could you please help me little bit further. That method exist in JAVA SE (http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) but not in Android **JSONObject** class (http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: Yep, it is in JavaSE not in Android. That's why I posted to explain the lacking of that method in Android JSONObject class

Comment: @AnujaPiyadigama .. this will help.. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names()

Comment: your first answer is not the correct answer, but you gave me a good hint. There is a method call `names' in **JSONObject** class in **Android** I think it will help to achieve my target. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Take String array and pass it in `jsonObject.getJSONArray(your array);`

Like

If you will try to get first object then pass

```
jsonObject.getJSONArray(array[pos]);
```

and in `array{"user","animal"};`

increase `pos` after getting all values from first object.

Comment: Either you have misunderstood my question or I am not clearly explain it. In your given solution I should aware with the parent Object tags. ("user", "animal", etc...). But in my question, I am assuming I can't see the JSON file and I want to read it programmatically ONLY and extract the parent Object names

Comment: Means you need code to getting object values...
Now m i right.?